# Ubuntu and Windows 8 dualbooting

Tags: boot, bios, boot-repair

I've downloaded and installed Ubuntu, but it won't boot it. It keeps booting into windows 8. I have been going through the advanced settings, shutdown/reboot thingy in Windows 8. I've disabled all the things in the BIOS that i should. I've run the Boot-Repair application but nothing helps! 
Please help!

Comment: Please indicate the URL provided by Boot-Repair.

Answer (score 1):

1.Download and install `EasyBCD` on windows.

2.On the linux section select grub2 and add entry for the partition where you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: remember to select the correct disk partition (/boot).